# When this ajax jquery trigger I want a image that loads for 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".a").live("click", function () {
            var $this = $(this),
        ProductImageId = $this.data('ProductImageId');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/AddToCart',
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                data: { ProductImageId: ProductImageId },
                success: function (data) {
                    data = eval(data);
                    $this.addClass('productSelected');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    $(".validation-summary-errors").append("<li>Error connecting to server.</li>");
                }

            });
        });
```

Every time someone click on this button I want a image to load for like 1 sec
so the user knows that something happened..

any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: "pretend that something happened" ?!?!

Comment: @David so the user knows that something happened..

Comment: why not just do it right and show the image for the length of time the ajax request is executing (ie, show it before, hide it in success and error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
var $loader = $('<img src="loader.gif">').appendTo(document.body);
```

And then

```
success: function (data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $loader.remove();
        data = eval(data);
        $this.addClass('productSelected');
    },1000);
}
```

It will show the image for 1sec + the ajax loading time. Although, as a visitor of your site I would probably prefer to skip the 1sec delay...

Comment: how can the user know that something happened on when they click on the button if not this? its a button that says "buy"

Comment: where should i have this line: var $loader = $('<img src="loader.gif">').appendTo(document.body);

Comment: @Avar put it in the click handler just before the `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 0):

Add before send like this :

```
beforeSend: function(){
    $("some element").append("<img src='url' id='one_sec_img' />");
    SetTimeout(1000, function(){
         $("#one_sec_img").hide();

     })
 }
```

But, I think your requirement is something normal  :
Here, bcoz of the before send, as soon as you click button that triggers ajax, the image will be loaded, and on success, the image can be hidden . This is the usual process, in this case,setTimeout is not needed . But, if your requirement is something like, the image should appear only one sec, you can use set timeout. Otherwise, below code is enough.

```
beforeSend: function(){
    $("some element").append("<img src='url' id='one_sec_img' />");

 },
success: function(res){
$("#one_sec_img").hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".a").click( function( ) {
    $("#idOfImage").show().delay( 1000 ).hide();
    // ajax call
});
```

else if you only want the image to disappear only after the ajax call

```
$(".a").click( function( ) {

        $("#idOfImage").show();

        $.ajax({
            // parameters
        }).done( function( ) {

            $("#idOfImage").hide( );
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".a").live("click", function () {
            var html=$(this).html();
            $(this).html('loading');//<img src="" /> 
            var $this = $(this),

        ProductImageId = $this.data('ProductImageId');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/AddToCart',
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                data: { ProductImageId: ProductImageId },
                success: function (data) {
                     $(".a").html(html);
                    data = eval(data);
                    $this.addClass('productSelected');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    $(".validation-summary-errors").append("<li>Error connecting to server.</li>");
                }

            });
        });
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery BlockUI Plugin to show the image, may be it solve your problem.